# Unity 5 C# collision problems

Tags: c#, unity

I want to make the built-in FPS controller collide with an object and switch a boolean to true. Here is my code:

```
public static bool WellGUIOn;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    WellGUIOn = false;
}


void OnCollisionEnter (Collision c)
{
    if (c.gameObject.name == "Well") {
        WellGUIOn = true;
    } else {
        WellGUIOn = false;
}
```

I have attached this script to the FPS controller and added a box collider on both prefabs (with is trigger ticked). The FPS controller already has a rigidbody(with kinematic ticked) and I added a rigidbody (with kinematic **NOT** ticked) to the object. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: How it does not work? Can you give us more information? Have you set breakpoint inside OnCollisionEnter that does that event even get called?

Comment: @Jon Koivula it doesn't work because the boolean doesn't get set to true.

Comment: Have you set breakpoint to that if line and see if the code does get there when colliding with prefabs.

Comment: @JonKoivula No, I haven't. Anyway, I might seem like a bit of a noob but how?

Comment: Google how to use breakpoints when debuggin. When you know how to do it, then you can see if that function is fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is always a good idea to use `Debug.Log()` when something goes wrong.

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision c)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision: " + gameObject.name + " | " + c.gameObject.name);
    if (c.gameObject.name == "Well") {
        WellGUIOn = true;
    } else {
        WellGUIOn = false;
}
```

You can now see if the function is called the way you intended.

---

> added a box collider on both prefabs (with is trigger ticked)

Assuming you are using 3D and not 2D, I think you might want to use [`OnTriggerEnter()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) instead of [`OnCollisionEnter()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) then?

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
{
    Debug.Log("Trigger: " + gameObject.name + " | " + c.gameObject.name);
    if (c.gameObject.name == "Well") {
        WellGUIOn = true;
    } else {
        WellGUIOn = false;
}
```

If you want to read more about Unity's collision system, here's [the Colliders Overview](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html).

Comment: Thank you!  In reply to the first bit, Jon Koivula said to use the breakpoint feature.

Answer (score 0):

In 2d mode, you must use `OnCollisionEnter2D`.

Example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour  {

  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
      coll.gameObject.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", 10);
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm not using 2d, but thanks. I'll use this for the future.